# Node mailer Error: can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, mongoose, nodemailer

I have Tried to send a mail once new resource created, And Before Creating a new user it should check email and employee number if any one of the values same it should display Already Exists or it will add new resource and have to send mail.

If email and emp no are not same, Its Perfectly created the resource and sending mail. But If i tried same mail or emp number am getting Error

My error:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\hourmint\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:7
30:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (D:\hourmint\node_modules\express\lib\response.js
:847:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (D:\hourmint\node_modules\express\lib\response.js
:885:18)
    at D:\hourmint\app\routes.js:298:18
    at D:\hourmint\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2917:18
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

My transmitter:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'noemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  },
});
```

My code:

```
app.post('/addresources', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  var id = (req.body._id) ? req.body._id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(0);
  var newPwd = new mongo.resource();

  var pwd = newPwd.generateHash(req.body.res_password);
  var resourceValue = {
    'role_id': req.body.role_id,
    'privilege_id': req.body.privilege_id,
    'res_fname': req.body.res_fname,
    'res_lname': req.body.res_lname,
    'res_email': req.body.res_email,
    'res_password': pwd,
    'res_empno': req.body.res_empno,
    'res_city': req.body.res_city,
    'res_mobile': req.body.res_mobile,
    'res_emerno': req.body.res_emerno,
    'res_hourlyrate': req.body.res_hourlyrate,
    'res_otp': 0,
    'res_status': req.body.res_status
  };

  mongo.resource.findOne({
    $or: [{
      'res_email': req.body.res_email
    }, {
      'res_empno': req.body.res_empno
    }]
  }).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (user) {
      console.log(user)
      if (user.res_email == req.body.res_email && user.res_empno == req.body.res_empno) {

        req.flash('error', 'Email And Employee Number Already Exists!!!')
        res.redirect('/resources')


      } //user already exists with email AND/OR phone.
      else if (user.res_email == req.body.res_email) {

        req.flash('error', 'Email Id  Already Exists!!!')
        res.redirect('/resources')


      } //no users with that email NOR phone exist.
      else(user.res_empno == req.body.res_empno) {

        req.flash('error', 'Employee Number Already Exists!!!')
        res.redirect('/resources')

      }
    } else {


      mongo.resource.findOneAndUpdate({
        '_id': id
      }, resourceValue, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;


        console.log("Resource Added SuccessFully")
        console.log(response.res_email)
        res.redirect('/resources')

        var mainOptions = {
          from: '"Niyati" <noemail@gmail.com>',
          to: response.res_email,
          subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
          text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
          html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
        };
        //console.log("html data ======================>", mainOptions.html);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mainOptions, function(err, info) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("mail Sent");
          // console.log(err);
        });

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is caused by a flaw in your if else condition. when the first if matches

```html
user.res_email == req.body.res_email && user.res_empno == req.body.res_empno
```

the else if statement will match as well. so res.redirect is triggered twice.

Please refine your if/else condition to make sure there is no overlapping.

Comment: Thanks For Replying... I Have used that condition to show flash message as Email And Employee Number is Already Exists,If Changed it means How i can Able to show that

Comment: add && user.res_empno != req.body.res_empno to second condition; add && user.res_email != req.body.res_email to the last condition

Comment: Thanks I Fixed the Error And Also In Last Else condition in If(User) I changed to else if